# Split word into two byte - Theory

Tags: math, theory

Just a little question about math..

I have a WORD with that value **25467**. I want to get two bytes (lo / hi) from that, that is **123** and **99**.
There's a way to calculate that two bytes only with a **calculator**, avoid bitmask (&&) or shifting (<< >>).

Something like
(25467 / x) - y = hi word
(25467 / x) * z = lo word?

Comment: Seems using bitwise operators and shifting would be *much, much* faster than any solution involving division and subtraction.

Comment: Solving for *x* gives, not surprisingly, `x=256`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Ya, I just try some division/moltiplication. 25467 / 256 = 99,48046875  then 25467 % 256 = 123. The problem is rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upper = word/(2^8)` and `lower = word modulo (2^8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting is equivalent with dividing with 2. So it you'd shift by 8 bit, that's dividing by 2^8:

```
wordValue = 25467;
hi = wordValue / 256;
low = wordValue - hi * 256
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the WORD is organized in the order: HIBYTE LOWBYTE, then  hi = (WORD)/256; low = WORD % 256